# SQL Server 2008 r2 Create trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

I am new to triggers and am have some difficulties I am trying to create a trigger that when someone logs into our WMS it logs how long users have been logged into the WMS and how long they have been idle for. I originally created this a Stored Procedure and it works great but when I tried to turn it into a Trigger it either does nothing or returns an Error.

I have tried putting the entire code into the trigger and just pointing the trigger at the Stored Procedure.

This is my current code and nothing happens even though the basic criteria have been met.

```
Use WMS;
Go

Create Trigger ExpiredUsersRmv
On LogFile
For Insert
As

--Total Users before stored procedure runs
Declare @TtlUsers Int
Set @TtlUsers = '7';
--Idle time limit
Declare @iTime DateTime
Set @iTime = '00:05:00';

If 
(
Select COUNT(USERID)
From dbo.LogFile
)>= @TtlUsers

Begin

  Insert Into dbo.ExpiredIdleUsersRmvd
  Select Working, e.USERID, e.CMPNYNAM, USRCLASS, tTime, iTime, LoginDatestamp, GETDATE() As cTime
  From dbo.ExpiredTime e Join inserted i on e.USERID = i.USERID
  Where iTime >= @iTime;

End
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things come to mind. Some of these are inferences based on the procedure you're posted, so if I've made incorrect assumptions there, please accept my apologies in advance.

First, your trigger is only going to fire if there are more than 7 records being inserted into LogFile, per the "If" block in the code, so are you sure that's what you want?

Second, I think you may be trying to use a DateTime in a manner a bit crosswise with its intent. It appears you're trying to use it as an "elapsed time" holder, when in reality it's trying to hold a specific point in time, eg May 23, 2004, 12:31:11 AM. If you're trying to measure elapsed time, I'd expect to see some DateDiffs...but just relying on the time portion of a date makes me raise my eyebrow as a possible problem. Your query condition, "where iTime >= iTime" looks very much like you're trying to say "where their idle time is in excess of five minutes," but in reality will look for a date following that inferred from the full value of @iTime.

You might want to consider a declaration of a "LastActivityDate" and then do a DateDiff(seconds, LastActivityDate, GetDate)> 300 to catch idletime of a certain amount..

Again, if I've misinterpreted what you're needing, my apologies.

Good luck.

**EDIT: More information**

Oh, goodness, I think you've overwritten that field in your view query. You're turning that datediff result into a string and its causing you all manner of difficulty. I would recommend the following:

- Modify that view for iTime to return the number of seconds elapsed since last_batch and now, eg datediff(second, p.last_batch,getdate()). Return it just as a plain old integer.
- In your removal test query, simply compare iTime against the number of seconds you want to use for your elapsed time criteria. Based on your sample, that's five mintues -> 300 seconds. That eliminates all the dicey datetime/string comparisons you were doing that I think are the source of your problem.

Give that a try and see what happens.

Comment: 7 records is just for testing the actual value will be >=35. I did not feel like logging in as 35 or more temp users.  dbo.ExpiredTime is a view and the iTime is just a name that I have give to that field from that view. The actual time comes from sys table and is called ElapsedTime. 5 minutes is just for testing the actual time wil be 2 hours or greater.

Comment: Okay. I still think your problem lies in how you're trying to use the DateTime...you're apparently intending to use that comparison to measure elapsed time, but it really is comparing two date values...which could be your problem.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, I have been wrestling with this for over two weeks. So why would this give me a problem in the trigger and not the stored procedure. There are DateDiffs but they are in the view.The cTime is just to log what time the user was removed from the WMS. Is it possible to shortcut the entire thing and just have the trigger fire the Stored Procedure. MY goal is to first check how many users, How long logged in, How long Active, then write to a table if the proper conditions are meet. After that a second Procedure is to fire that will remove those users from select tables

Comment: I don't think there's a benefit to having the trigger fire the proc, because a trigger, itself, is just a stored proc. What is the unit returned in the DateDiff in the view, and what is the type of the iTime field? If there are datediffs in the view, you could just be doing the wrong kind of comparison in the trigger.

Comment: RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(CONVERT(char(2), DATEDIFF(ss, P.last_batch, GETDATE()) / (60 * 60))), 2) 
+ ':' + RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(CONVERT(char(2), DATEDIFF(ss, P.last_batch, GETDATE()) / 60 % 60)), 2) 
+ ':' + RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(CONVERT(char(2), DATEDIFF(ss, P.last_batch, GETDATE()) % 60)), 2) AS iTime

Comment: My view is seeing iTime as a Varchar(8) not DateTime so could that be the problem? If so how do I get the View to see iTime as DateTime?

Comment: I've got several suggestions based on your last response, so I modified my original answer. Take a look and see if that is helpful...think we finally got to the root of the problem. @user1009629

Comment: I wish I could that worked but it was a bust. I got the following Error message.  "A save operation on table 'SY_Current_LogFile' failed accessing SQL data"

Comment: Well, don't give up. I still think this is the right track. Push through and find the specific source of this error, and keep plugging.